# WMI Scripting Windows 8 error

Tags: powershell, windows-8, wmi, windows-scripting

I have a problem with WMI in a machine with a Windows 8 Home Edition. I need to catch the CPU usage and the ProcessID by process. I've tried so many ways:

- ShellExecute in Delphi
- A *.bat with the code
- A *.vbs
- A *.vbs executed by a *.bat
- A *.ps1
- A *.ps1 executed by a *.bat

(Maybe some of these ways can be really stupid, but I've tried anyway)

In the User-Click it works perfectally, but by a standalone applicantion it doesn't work.
I have opened the Security on WMIMGMT.msi of some folders and the execution policy (in PowerShell) now is UNRESTRICTED.

This is the code on the *.ps1 file:

```
$ErrorActionPreference = "SilentlyContinue"
Stop-Transcript | Out-Null
$ErrorActionPreference = "Continue"
$perflist = (get-wmiobject Win32_PerfFormattedData_PerfProc_Process)
foreach ($p in $peflist) {
  "" + $p.IDProcess + ";" + $p.PercentProcessTime
}
```

This is the code on *.bat

```
powershell -ExcetutionPolicy Unrestricted -File "C:\Somefolder\PP.ps1" > C:\SomeFolder\output.txt
```

All I got is this output:

```
get-wmiobject : Invalid query "select * from Win32_Win32_PerfFormattedData_PerfProc_Process"
In C:\Somefolder\PP.ps1:4 character: 14
+ $perflist = (get-wmiobject Win32_PerfFormattedData_PerfProc_Process)
+          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     + CategoryInfo         : InvalidArgument: (:) [Get-WmiObject], ManagementException
     + FullyQualifiedErroID : GetWMIManagementException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetWmiObjectCommand
```

---

**Edit1:** The code copied as asked:

- *.ps1:

  ```
  $ErrorActionPreference="SilentlyContinue" 
  Stop-Transcript | out-null 
  $ErrorActionPreference = "Continue"
  $perflist = (get-wmiobject Win32_PerfFormattedData_PerfProc_Process) 
  foreach ($p in $perflist) {
    "" + $p.IDProcess + ";" + $p.PercentProcessorTime
  }
  ```
- *.bat

  ```
  powershell -executionPolicy unrestricted -file "C:\MonitorPerformance\test.ps1" > C:\MonitorPerformance\output1.txt
  ```
- Output: (Consulta inválida = Invalid Query; No = in; caractere = character)

  ```
  get-wmiobject : Consulta inv lida "select * from Win32_PerfFormattedData_PerfProc_Process"
  No C:\MonitorPerformance\test.ps1:4 caractere:14
  + $perflist = (get-wmiobject Win32_PerfFormattedData_PerfProc_Process)
  +              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Get-WmiObject], ManagementException
      + FullyQualifiedErrorId : GetWMIManagementException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetWmiObjectCommand
  ```

Comment: Are you able to query other things with WMI?

Comment: The error message in your question was caused by an invalid class name (`Win32_Win32_PerfFormattedData_PerfProc_Process`), which you corrected. Are you still getting an error?

Comment: I don't have tested another class with WMI. If you can tell me a code to test, I'll be thankful
And to explain, the code in the win8 machine was right, but I wrote wrong the code here

Comment: Yes, I still have the error

Comment: I got news
I changed 
`$perflist = (get-wmiobject Win32_PerfFormattedData_PerfProc_Process)
foreach ($p in $peflist) {
  "" + $p.IDProcess + ";" + $p.PercentProcessTime
}`

to:
`get-wmiobject Win32_OperatingSystem` (just a test)

and  it works! I still have no idea about what's going on...

Comment: It's clearly not possible that you got the error you posted from a script where you run `get-wmiobject Win32_PerfFormattedData_PerfProc_Process`. Please edit your question and post the *exact* code and error message. Copy and paste it. Don't paraphrase. Don't type from memory.

Comment: Ok, I'll make that effort (This win8 machine is in a server in another state from my country) (and the language is pt-br, so I'll  translate it again)

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers, that's it

Comment: Can you start `wbemtest`, connect and enumerate instances of that class? Also try running [WMIDiag](http://blogs.technet.com/b/askperf/archive/2015/05/12/wmidiag-2-2-is-here.aspx).

Comment: I can see it with the _wbemtest_ , **I have the idea of make a x64 dummy program to execute the *.bat and... IT INCREDIBLY WORKS!** I still get so pissed off with the Win8... Thank you for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows 8 does not performs WMI actions perfectly when you use x32 applications, **I made a dummy x64 application who executes the *.bat and it finally works.** Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 0):

replace this:

```
$perflist = (get-wmiobject Win32_Win32_PerfFormattedData_PerfProc_Process)
```

with this:

```
$perflist = (get-wmiobject Win32_PerfFormattedData_PerfProc_Process)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, dude, but I wrote wrong my code here (I'm copying from another machine)

Comment: @NickG. Then you need to change your question as the error indicated that this was the issue. Do you still get invalid query?

Comment: @Matt I didn't understand your help, the error doesn't consists in remove the "Win32" from "Win32_Win32_PerfFormattedData_PerfProc_Process", but it consists in the windows 8 does not allow standalone aplicattions use WMI.